# css modules - Unsafe member access .fieldset on an `any` value

Tags: typescript, css-modules, typescript-eslint

I have tried putting this into my index.d.ts file

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const value: Record<string, string>;
  export default value;
}

declare module '*.css' {
  const value: Record<string, string>;
  export default value;
}
```

OR

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const value: {[key: string]: string}
  export default value;
}

declare module '*.css' {
  const value: {[key: string]: string}
  export default value;
}
```

Now when importing via typescript file

```
import style from './_fieldset.module.scss';

export const Fieldset: FC<PropChildren> = ({ children }) => (
  <fieldset className={style.fieldset}>{children}</fieldset> // error style.fieldset
);
```

> Unsafe member access .fieldset on an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out eslint have some odd restrictions on this despite its not defined as 'any'.
I've just set this to zero in my eslint config and its removed the errors

```js
{
  '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access': 0;
  '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment': 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution affect all files? What if i want keep that restriction but avoid error for className use? did you find some better solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's was a litle hard for me undestand the real cause and how to solve.

There is many package out there that try to solve this issue like:

- [vite-plugin-css-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-css-modules)
- [ts-css-modules-vite-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-css-modules-vite-plugin)

But, they are just eslint plugins that adapt some solution to avoid the eslint error. They doesn't resolve "compiler/typescript" validation. (Please correct me if I wrong about this sentence).

I noted in the [Vite Features](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css-modules) that Vite includes this `CSS module` concept, but it is necessary to add some parameters in `vite.config.ts`

This is mine `vite.config.ts`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    css: {
        modules: {
        localsConvention: 'camelCaseOnly',
        generateScopedName: '[local]_[hash:base64:2]',
    },
 },
})
```

**If all `tsconfig.json` is propertly configurated the `@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access` issue disappear.**

[More info in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sgcfiow4fVQ)